# Error: Failed to install provider Error while installing hashicorp/credstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/credstash: provider registry
registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/credstash

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "3.73.0"
  region  = "ap-south-1"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "ap-south-1"
}

provider "credstash" {
  region  = var.region
}

TF version: 0.13.7
```

Answer (score 2):

The `credstash` provider isn't a HashiCorp provider so it isn't in their namespace.
From the `use provider` button on the [provider page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-mars/credstash/0.5.1) it's in the `terraform-mars` namespace:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    credstash = {
      source = "terraform-mars/credstash"
      version = "0.5.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "credstash" {
  # Configuration options
}
```

Comment: Still I can see the below error:
```
Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing terraform-mars/credstash v0.5.1: could not query
provider registry for registry.terraform.io/terraform-mars/credstash: failed
to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2
attempts, please try again later: Get
"https://github.com/terraform-mars/terraform-provider-credstash/releases/download/v0.5.1/terraform-provider-credstash_0.5.1_SHA256SUMS":
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: I just tested in a new folder and the terraform init works fine. The certificate error sounds like something on your network intercepting SSL certs (maybe a proxy?). I've seen security in corporate networks block terraform provider downloads before.